# How to use wordpress Contact Form 7 plugin with magnific popup

Tags: form-submit, page-refresh, magnific-popup, contact-form-7

I have created wordpress theme and i am using [contact form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin for making forms. Now, i have a requirement of making a form in popup, so i have decided to to use [magnific-popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) to launch popup and placed shortcode of form in there. Now i have popup with working in working condition.

The problem is `validations`, when i click on `submit` it `refreshes` the page and closes the poppup, and validations are gone with the popup, now the user have to again click on link and launch the popup in order to see the validations and to proceed further.

I want the popup to remain open until form is being submitted successfully and after submit i will redirect the user onto another page.

Comment: I also have same issue.have you solved that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, if you click submit-button, page reloads and you have to open popup once again to see validations or thanks-message.

What i found out is that i didn't have wp_head() and wp_footer() in templates.

So maybe this will help:

http://contactform7.com/why-isnt-my-ajax-contact-form-working-correctly/